# Custom content issue in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to add some informations on description.php page from Woocommerce, but I can't see the result.

For a specific product, I try to add specific information. I've done this way :

```
<?php

function my_function_name() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_id() !== 96 ) {
        return;
    }

    echo ('Information I want to display');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_function_name', 10);
?>
```

Once I go back to my product page, I can't see the result, nothing happens. I'm not sure where I've failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem was the hook priority… I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** The problem is in the hook priority. Priority `10` is already used by product tabs:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

So if you need:

- To display that **before** the product tabs, the priority needs to be between `1` and `9`…
- To display that **after** the product tabs, the priority needs to be between `11` and `19`…

So this example will display it before the product tabs *(priority is `5` below)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_function_name', 5 );
function my_function_name() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_id() != 96 )
        return;

    echo __( 'Information I want to display', 'woocommerce');
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

It should work